# AWS S3 VPC endpoint docs example

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nat, amazon-vpc

Based on the "Example: An Endpoint Route in a Route Table" in

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html

Once the S3 VPC endpoint is applied, all traffic destined for S3 in that same region goes through the endpoint while all other traffic goes through the IGW.

Assuming that I have the same setup but in a private subnet and for all other traffic I am using a NAT(in a public subnet with IGW) and not IGW, would the traffic destined for S3 still go through the S3 VPC endpoint or would it be going through the NAT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will go through the endpoint not through NAT. The VPC endpoint is for all subnets in the VPC - whether it is private or public doesn't matter. **private connection between your VPC and another AWS service without requiring access over the Internet, through a NAT device**.

How did you miss the diagram in the same page you mentioned? It shows clearly the traffic from both types of subnets go to the S3 endpoint without NAT or IGW.

[image]

Comment: Actually, that diagram shows only the private subnet actually using the VPC endpoint.  It isn't in the route table for the public subnet, so the public subnet would not be using it, in this diagram.   It if isn't in the route table for the subnet, it isn't used by machines on that subnet.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you are correct. The route table doesn't show a route for the VPC endpoint. But OP asked about the route in the private subnet. If the VPC is created manually, you have to add the VPC endpoint route to the route table. But if you use the VPC wizard, it automatically adds the route to all subnets.

Comment: I have seen the diagram; my use case states that the private subnet should have internet access as well through a NAT which sits in the public subnet which is unlike the diagram, i.e. in the route table for the private subnet there is no route to the internet isn't there?.

Comment: Did you create the VPC manually or using the VPC wizard? Looks like you created it manually. Is there a NAT running in the public subnet? If yes, then add an entry to the routing table to route all non local traffic to NAT. When you add a route, the dialog will show all available options - you choose the NAT instance's id. If there is no NAT running, add one to public subnet and then add a route for it in private subnet. Try using a VPC wizard and create another dummy VPC. Browse its routing table to understand how route to internet works.